# Чи нормативно вживати слово "крокіс" для означення рослин роду Crocus?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

СУМ-11

> [Крокіс](http://sum.in.ua/s/krokis) 1. (Carthamus crocus). Багаторічна декоративна трав'яниста
>   рослина з яскравими жовтогарячими квітками, зібраними в кошикоподібні
>   суцвіття; дикий шафран.
>
> [Шафран](http://sum.in.ua/s/shafran)  (Crocus, L.). Багаторічна трав'яниста рослина родини
>   півникових перев. з оранжево-жовтими квітами.
>
> [Крокус](http://sum.in.ua/s/krokus) 1, у, чол. Те саме, що крокіс.

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81)

> Шафран, крокіс, крокус - синоніми

Проте в СУМ-20 має інші визначення слів "крокус" та "крокіс"

> [Крокус](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=45443&page=1437) Багаторічна трав'яниста рослина родини півникових з
>   яскравими квітками; шафран.
>
> [Крокіс](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=45433&page=1437) ко́су, ч. Те саме, що нагі́дки́.

Нагідки це інший рід рослин, взято з СУМ-11. (СУМ-20 хоч і написано, що додано до слова "настувати", проте шукає лише до "мішурний")

> [Нагідки](http://sum.in.ua/s/naghidky) нагідок, мн. (одн. нагідка, и, жін.) (Calendula L.). Рід
>   трав'янистих та півкущових рослин родини складноцвітих з
>   оранжево-жовтими квітками, зібраними в кошики.

Стаття в [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD_(%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B4)) має назву "Шафран (рід)", а картинка зправа підписана "крокус".

Коли пише про квітку шафран (crocus) чи нормативно використовувати слово *"крокіс"*? Чи варто надати перевагу лише словам ***"шафран"*** та ***"крокус"***.

Answer (score 1):

Крок**і**с та шафран - це різні рослини:

1. [Крокіс](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%81) - рід **однорічних**, **рідше** дворічних або багаторічних рослин **родини Айстрових**.
2. Шафран або крокус - рід трав'янистих **багаторічних** рослин **родини Півникових** .

Крім того, шафран використовують як прянощі, а крокіс - ні.

І врахуйте, що Вікіпедія в обох випадках дає посилання на [Енциклопедію українознавства](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).